# siunitx displaying wrong uncertainty values for integers

Tags: siunitx

I am getting incorrect uncertainties displayed for integer-valued numbers using the `siunitx` package. It seems to insert one decimal place and divide the uncertainty I specify by 10.

This is a new problem since upgrading to the 2014-09-29 package version.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{siunitx} 
\sisetup{separate-uncertainty = true} % use +/- symbol for uncertainty values

\begin{document}

Using integers, 

\verb+\num{30 \pm 2}+ gives \num{30 \pm 2}

but I want the value to appear as \num{30} 

and the uncertainty should be \num{\pm 2} with no decimal parts.

Same problem happens using \verb+\SI+ and in tables using S-columns.

Things seem to work fine if the base value is not an integer:

\verb+\num{30.5 \pm 2}+ gives \num{30.5 \pm 2}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This seems like a bug in `siunitx`; with the version in TeX Live 2013 I get “30 ± 2”.

Comment: In such cases the best is to inform the author @JosephWright.

Comment: This will be fixed in the next release of the package

Comment: This bug seems similar to a bug I have just posted about here https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/446074/wrong-value-with-decimals-and-uncertainty-in-siunitx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try it with:

```
\num{30(2)}
```

This works for me, if I only change the uncertainty in the `\num` command.

Comment: That works! Now, any tips on how to replace dozens of instances of `\pm x` with `(x)`?

Comment: Unfortunately, not. Maybe with any kind of script? But I am really not into this.

Comment: Thanks anyway for the answer. At least I can get the output I need.

Comment: I figured out how to use regexp in TeXworks' replace function: Put `([0-9\.]*) \\pm ([0-9\.]*)` in the `Replace:` field and `\1(\2)` in the `With:` field, and run the magic with `Replace` or `Replace All`.