# Can siunitx parse uncertainty values (the bracketed values) in the same magnitude as the main value in a table?

Tags: siunitx

I'd like to have `117.3(11.1)` parse as `117.3 \pm 11.1`. Is this possible to achieve **in a table**? Currently sunitx somehow regards the bracketed value as too small so it's all wrong.

Note: this question about parsing numbers **in a table**, not via `\num` in running text, such as addressed in [this question as of 4 days ago](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/204275/siunitx-displaying-wrong-uncertainty-values-for-integers).

### version of siunitx

> Package: siunitx 2014/09/27 v2.6b A comprehensive (SI) units package

### Picture of MWE

[image]

### MWE

```
\documentclass[
a4paper
]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{
lmodern,
booktabs
}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage[
per-mode=fraction,
locale=DE,
separate-uncertainty=true,
retain-explicit-plus,
binary-units,
]{siunitx}


\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
    \item Status quo: \verb+\num{111.26(13.45)}+: \num{111.26(13)} (obviously I omitted the \verb+.45+ as it wouldn't work)
    \item What I want: to have \verb+\num{111.26(13.45)}+ parse as \num{111.26 \pm 13.45}
\end{itemize}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{S[table-format=3.2(2)]S[table-format=3.2(2)]}
\toprule
{Status quo} & {Wish}\\
111.26(13) & \num{111.26 \pm 13.45}\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you're not inputting the material as `111.26(1345)` in the table and as `\num{111.26(1345)}` in running text?

Comment: @Mico The data comes straight out of Excel by the help of Excel2LateX and so there it is. Why would anyone delete the decimal markers in the original data, whether it's Excel, Calc, some .csv-file...?

Comment: That's a question for the package's author and maintainer, I suppose.

Comment: @Mico Formatting the data like this would/should lead to errors in the future, if one were to re-compile the document with an updated version of siunitx.

Comment: Short answer here is going to be 'no' as `111.26(13.45)` is _wrong_: bracket uncertainties refer to the least significant digits. Here your accuracy also does not support the number of figures you have: `111(13)` is all you can say.

Comment: Or you try to force Excel to spit out `\num{111.26+-13.45}` instead of the brackets. But as Joseph says, you are mixing two different cases here.

Comment: @JosephWright I see. Read about it for a while and I think I found a (or the) source of explanation: [bottom of p. 25 in the file up top on this site](http://www.bipm.org/en/publications/guides/gum.html).

Comment: @henry To be clear, when I say 'wrong' I mean _`siunitx` uses a defined format for uncertainties and it does not cover the format you use'. The code already has to deal with a variety of input formats, and adding more would be very tricky! (I am working on version 3 and will consider this, but it looks quite hard.)

Comment: @JosephWright I gathered you are factually right as the "official" recommendations are: "x = 100,021 47(35) g, where the number in parentheses is the numerical value of (the combined standard uncertainty) uc referred to the corresponding last digits of the quoted result." So... well done I suppose! Very frustrating though for noobs though who weren't aware of the foundation and just want to go ahead with the writing and things.

Comment: @JosephWright Besides the precision aspect is also a good recommendation. That could be attributed to noise anyway I think. :)

Comment: @JosephWright: independant from this question. Are you sure the output of `\num{123 +- 4.5}` in the documentation (p. 21) is correct? I would have expected `123.0(45)` and not `123.00(45)`

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I'll take a look: that does seem to be wrong.

Comment: @JosephWright Imho it is related to this message http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/204275/siunitx-displaying-wrong-uncertainty-values-for-integers

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Probably: I've tracked down what I think the issue is. The code for the conversion here is a bit tricky, and I think needs revision for the next major release.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just as you would write `\num{111.26(1345)}` in running text, you should write `111.26(1345)` in an `S` column.

*Aside*: As Joseph Wright has already observed in a comment, you're providing an unrealistic amount of precision with regard to the uncertainty component; `111(13)` would be more useful and realistic.