# Wrong value with Decimals and Uncertainty in siunitx

Tags: siunitx

I am using [siunitx](https://ctan.org/pkg/siunitx?lang=en) to typeset values with uncertainty, and I'm getting (what I think is) the wrong value in some cases. I'm using `separate-uncertainty=true` because it makes my examples clearer, but the problem occurs either way.

First, note that `\num{3}` produces `3` while `\num{3.}` produces `3.0`. I don't really agree with this choice, but it's reasonable because otherwise the decimal wouldn't mean anything. This is directly relevant to the problem I'm having.

The number `\num{3 \pm 3}` yields `3±3`, as I expect. **However, `\num{3. \pm 3.}` yields `3.0 ± 0.3`, which I do not expect.** This is true for values in scientific notation, too; `\num{3. \pm 3. e10}` yields `(3.0 ± 0.3) × 10^{10}`. Whether the uncertainty value has a decimal doesn't seem to matter: `\num{3. \pm 3.}` gives the same incorrect result as `\num{3. \pm 3}`.

A minimal example is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
\num[separate-uncertainty=true]{3  \pm 3}
\num[separate-uncertainty=true]{3. \pm 3.}
\num[separate-uncertainty=true]{3. \pm 3. e10}
\num[separate-uncertainty=true]{3. \pm 3}
\end{document}
```

From the logfile, the version of siunitx is:

```
Package: siunitx 2016/03/01 v2.6q A comprehensive (SI) units package
```

I *think* this means the bug mentioned in [a different question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/204275/siunitx-displaying-wrong-uncertainty-values-for-integers) about integer values being typeset with a decimal has already been fixed, but I'm not sure.

My question is, what is going on here? Is there a way to avoid this behavior?

Edit: This question came about because I'm generating a data-rich table using a float format specifier (`(fX.Y)` in Fortran). If the number of digits to print after the decimal is zero, the decimal is still printed. I can modify this specific behavior - if the trailing character is a decimal, remove it - and I'll probably make this change. However, I would like to understand the behavior better, avoid it by other means if possible, and let others know about the issue.

Comment: Is there a reason for writing `3.`?

Comment: I've added something to the question to answer your question @egreg . Basically, I don't have to but it's inconvenient to fix.

Comment: Clearly a bug: I'll have to think whether it's fixable in the 2.x series (3.x is now working at a core level, for testing, and the bug isn't present.)

Comment: Thanks for the response - let me know what you decide. I have my workaround working now, but it wouldn't surprise me if others haven't noticed it occurring.

Comment: Also, @JosephWright, if you make an answer specifically describing what's bugged and what's as-designed (ie, `3.` interpreted as `3.0` is ok, but uncertainty of `0.3` is wrong), I'd be happy to accept it.